# Using jquery.ajax() to search db and getting "Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, dom

I am using jquery.ajax() to search a db table and return the data to a div on my page.

When clicking the search link the script fails at returning the usrObj to the div, and throws the msg **Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8**.

I was told this can be caused by a syntactical error? But I'm not seeing the problem...

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
//hide default articles
$("ul a").click(function(event){
     $(".short_article").addClass("hidden");
}); 

  $('#search-box').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'faq/search.php?',
        data: 'Term=body',
        success: function(jqXHR){
            var usrObj = $.parseJSON(jqXHR);
            $('#load_window').html (usrObj);
            alert ("Search failed"); //no alert displays

        }
    });
    return false;
});

});

<div id="load_window"></div>
```

Comment: So if you comment out the line: `$('#load_window').html (usrObj);` does it still throw an error? What is in the variable `usrObj`?

Comment: If I did comment it out the error would have been eliminated. The usrObj is holding the data that is being returned from the database (I think. this is a project I'm helping with, so some of it is not my code). I am still trying to format it into a usable state. Possibly with something similar to $('#load_window').text(usrObj.result);  I'm new to the stack still getting used to inserting code into comments..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the space after "html":

```
$('#load_window').html (usrObj);
```

...should be

```
$('#load_window').html(usrObj);
```

Comment: I have tried both, with and without a space (by accident) however it has no effect on the outcome.

Comment: What is in the `userObj`?  Try doing text() instead of html() just to see if that's where our problem is.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance.  PM your address and I will send a bill.

Comment: Also, just wanted to say you may take advantage of the `<pre>` tag if you use `html(): '<pre>' + usrObj + '</pre>'`

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 issues with the code. Third could be relevant. But first two make your code hard to understand.

- First. Header of success callback is following: function(data,
  textStatus, jqXHR). So follow this naming. Otherwise your code is confusing.
- Second. In case you expect json as a response from a server script add "dataType: 'json'" option to the ajax() call. This will
  ensure your callback will receive "data" which is already a Json
  object. So there won't be need in parseJSON(). If you expect HTML -- dataType has to be 'html' and all json handling should be removed then.
- Third. You are trying to html() the Json object. However this method
  expects string. So, it is highly probable html() gets a bit crazy and
  throws the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The header for success is formatted that way to stay within the code formatting implemented by my employer (this is a requirement). I will use the dataType: json suggestion, thanks. And the third thing about the html() for json, that was the main problem.  It is now $('#load_window').text(usrObj); and is not throwing an error. I need to format the response though with usrObj.result or a similar method.